# Table.read() function gives [Object Promise] how to turn this into array? Cordova and Microsoft Azure mobile app service

Tags: javascript, azure, promise

So I am making a login system for my mobile app using Visual Studio tools for Cordova and Azure mobile app easy tables. My problem is: If I call the table.read() function:

```js
  var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://passmateapp.azurewebsites.net');


var table = client.getTable('todoitem');

            var test = table.read();
console.log(test);
```

This is what I get: [Object Promise] I have seen tutorials and guides on the internet on how to process this into a string or an array but I didn't really understand them. So my question is can someone please explain to me how to process this promise into an array that I can use for my login system? Thank you very much!

In reply to an answer:

[Contents of the promise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWEFV.png)

If I try to open the drop down any further this happens:
[error message when opening drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CijpP.png)

Comment: Use the basic promise syntax: `client.getTable().then( table => table.read()).then( table => { var test = table; });` Or something like that. The clue is that you need to chain a callback function using `.then()` to the async call, so it will only run once the promise resolves.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for Promise to resolve. Use `then` method on Promise object that accepts callback to receive data.

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://passmateapp.azurewebsites.net');
var table = client.getTable('todoitem');
table.read().then(function(data) {console.log(data)});
```

Comment: If I try this nothing gets console logged what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Promise works asynchronously, meaning that it doesn't block execution of following code so console.log(test) below the promise call  will still be undefined as it takes time to get the response back.

I looked through documentation for [WindowsAzure tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-html-how-to-use-client-library), and I want you to try this:

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://passmateapp.azurewebsites.net');
var table = client.getTable('todoitem');
let test;


function success(results) {
    test = results;
    // do you see correct data here?
    console.log('results:', test);
    return test;
 }

 function failure(error) {
     throw new Error('Error loading data: ', error);
 }

async function setTestValue() {
    if (!test) {
        test = await table.read().then(success, failure);
    }
    console.log('test: ', test);
}
setTestValue();
```

Comment: If I try this nothing gets console logged what could be wrong?

Comment: Right, my bad. Promise acts asynchronously, so the code below (the console log) doesn't wait for it to finish and continues to execute, and the test value didn't get the value assigned yet at that point. I'll add a possible work around to my answer

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again but if I use this code I get the same [Object Promise] message.

Comment: @FLIMMER hmm ok. Do you mind to post the result of `console.log` of the `data` returned inside of the promise (within curly braces where the data is assigned to `result`?

Comment: I am not sure wether this is what you mean but I added it to my question! The images can be found by clicking on the links!

Comment: This may seem a bit weird but if I try this code nothing gets console logged!